# Can Silver Surfer kill Galactus in comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, silver-surfer, galactus

In the end of *Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer* movie, Silver Surfer killed Galactus. I couldn't digest it because it was Galactus who awarded Power Cosmic to Silver Surfer in the first place.

I haven't read too much comics of Silver Surfer, but as per Silver Surfer cartoon of 90s, Galactus has given Silver Surfer only small amount of Power Cosmic and possibly he can take it away from him.

I am interested to know what comics say about this. Can Silver Surfer kill Galactus? I am skeptical because even Thanos with Infinity Gauntlet had hard time subduing Galactus.

There are two heavily related parts of this question:

- Can Silver Surfer kill Galactus if Galactus doesn't do a thing (sleeping, didn't notice Surfer etc)? Means, is killing Galactus under capability of Silver Surfer?
- Can Galactus stop Silver Surfer by taking away Power Cosmic within a flick of a second? Means, can Silver Surfer kill Galactus after announcing that he was going to kill him (exact movie scenario)?

Comment: If I give you a gun, can you still shoot me with it?

Comment: In the comics, Galactus says he's going to remove SS's powers and then hits him with a beam. It's instantaneous, but does take more than just saying it.

Comment: @Adamant - Sure - but, relative to Galactus's power level, the "gun" is a Nerf gun.

Comment: @RDFozz - ...it would seem not.

Comment: @Adamant - in that movie, true. In the comics, I don't believe it is. At least, I can't recall a comics story where the Surfer was shown attacking Galactus, and being more than a distraction.

Comment: @Adamant The analogy isn't correct. If your body is made of gun stuff, then go ahead and give me a gun. Correct analogy can be you are inside a tank and you give me a gun.

Answer (score 5):

No.

In the comics, the Silver Surfer cannot kill Galactus. Reed Richards even theorizes that Galactus is a force of nature, like Eternity and Infinity; a force of nature that existed before our current universe and one which will exist into the next universe long after this one is gone. In *Fantastic Four* #242-244 (1982), when encountering Galactus at a point where he is near death, Reed actually saves him; based on these theories, he's a necessary evil.

This is confirmed in *Fantastic Four* #262 (1984) by Eternity during the trail of Reed Richards by alien races whose homeworlds Galactus has destroyed. Eternity allows everyone present to become one with the universe and they understand that Galactus is part of the cosmic natural order, allowing Reed to go free.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, yes. When combined with the power of the [Cosmic Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube), the Silver Surfer was able to easily destroy Galactus, shortly after having remade him.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Silver Surfer - Last Days #3**](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/52508/silver_surfer_vol_3_last_days_trade_paperback)</sup></sub>